# Jinja2 to load new data

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, jinja2

I have been spending two days but can't figure out.

This prints out the different values every time in the line `print value` in `index()` but once it goes to html through `render_template('index.html', car_value=value)`, it does not seem to receive new different values. `console.log(y)` only keeps printing out the first received value, not getting the other values passed after the first value.

Please let me know how to pass and make `index.html` able to receive those new values through `Flask` and `Jinja2`

---

EDIT after Amadan's help

```
def get_data():
    df = sqlio.read_sql(qry1, conn)
    value = df['count'][0]
    return value

@app.route('/get_data', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_data_route():
    value = get_data()
    return value

@app.route('/get_car_value', methods=['GET'])
def get_car_value():
    data = "{ car_value: %s }" % get_data_route()
    return data, 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        port=8000,
        host='0.0.0.0'
    )
```

And

```
$(function() {
    var chart;
    $('#car_id').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "/get_car_value",
                            success: function(data) {
                                var y = data.car_value;
                                console.log(y)
                                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                            }
                       });
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        },
```

Still not working... It's not printing out anything in `console.log`

Comment: It's solved with Amadan's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you always access the same URL with AJAX, chances are good it is being cached. Try adding this at the top of the Flask controller responsible for the data AJAX:

```
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0'
response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
response.headers['Expires'] = '-1'
```

Alternately, you can change your URL to:

```
url: "/?" + new Date().getTime(),
```

so it's impossible to cache (since it will be different each time).

**EDIT**: I just noticed, you're setting the value of `y` in the template, which has no relevance to the AJAX call. To refresh that value, you would have to reload the page, AJAX is useless as it stands, since it fetches some data and then *ignores it*.

```
url: '/get_car_value',
success: function(data) {
  var y = data.car_value;
  console.log(y)
  series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
}
```

and make a new controller:

```
@app.route('/get_car_value', methods=['GET'])
def get_car_value():
    import json
    data = json.dumps({ car_value: get_data_route() })
    return data, 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

(you could use the existing `get_data_route` controller, but I like a consistent API, and always using JSON when transfering data with AJAX is pretty useful).

**EDIT**: JSON brain fart.

Comment: I did but still not working. Can you see my update? So frustrating

Comment: OH! I just noticed, you're getting `car_value` from the *template*, not from the AJAX call!

Comment: Yeah I need to pass and update the `car_value` in the template so that the template is rendered with new different values and show the different plots every time

Comment: Nononono, you should definitely *not* have `car_value` in the template. I updated my answer - you should be getting it from AJAX response.

Comment: Thanks, then how would you write `index()` trying to figure out

Comment: `index` does not need `car_value`, nor `get_data_route()` call. Leave data generation to the AJAX routine.

Comment: I updated my writing. Still not working... :( Your answer makes sense but I don't know why it is not printing anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59235/discussion-between-amadan-and-epsilonsdfsdfdsf).

Comment: I have question on HighCharts, Python and Flask. Can you help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639465/flask-python-ajax-displaying-data-from-2-different-routes-in-the-same-highchart